# code vba to insert a row from a column

Tags: vba, excel

[image]I have a file with refund data where I need to insert a line but not from column A but rather leave columns A, B ....., I intact and insert the line from column F if Cels (i, A) = Cels (i + 1, A), watch a screenshot of my table to understand thank you i tried thi code but it didnt work.

```
Sub match()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


With Worksheets("Feuil1") 'Nom de feuille à adapter
DerLig = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To DerLig
    For j = i + 1 To DerLig

    If .Cells(i, "A") = .Cells(j, "A") Then
    Cells(j, 11).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert

    End If

    Next j
    Next i

End With
End Sub
[![table screen shot][1]][1]
```

Comment: You can't insert a row and leave certain columns intact, your only option would be to shift the data from columns J:L down one row.

Comment: yeah that interst me, because i need to have the same informations if Cels (i, A) = Cels (i + 1, A), so how can i shift the data dow one row ? thanks

Comment: Attempt it and ask us if you get stuck. I'd recommend detecting the extents of the data (similar to how you do for DerLig), loading it into an array `arrayVariable = range(cells(x,10),cells(dataEnd,12))` then shifting the data down `range(cells(x+1,10),cells(dataend+1,12)) = arrayVariable` and clearing the top row of selected data that is now duplicate `range(cells(x,10),cells(x,12)).clearcontents`